# How to build a Search functionality to search multiple models like GitHub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering on how to implement a search functionality like Github.
Just one search box on the top header right and when searched for a keyword, displays the results for Repository, Code and User.

Is there any tutorial or example to implement this on Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are really good they're doing separate searches across the tables for the same value, then combining the results afterwards.

Use Rails to create a small form containing a text field. When it's submitted take the value of the field and do a query using that as the search term.

If you're not sure how to do queries using ActiveRecord, see "[Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)" for a nice overview.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do several queries, one per model, and put the results together on the same view.

If your question is "how do I do full text searches on several activerecord models in a DRY way" then there are basically two paths:

The common solution, but a bit complex, is using a dedicated daemon on your machine, like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Sphinx is a service in (like Apache or MySQL) that indexes your content and allows you to do searches. You can use the [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) gem to communicate with it easily from rails. An alternative to Sphinx is [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (there's also a gem for it called [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/))

If you are using Postgresql, there's a simpler alternative that doesn't require external services running on your server. Postgresql has with some full-text search capabilities built-in. There's a gem called [texticle](https://github.com/tenderlove/texticle) that helps using these services from rails. You can have that working very quickly.